# Laravel error - Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 71

Tags: laravel-4, environment-variables

I am not sure as to what is causing this error.

```
(!) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 71
```

I think it might be an environment variable issue. But I am not sure.

The Call Stack

```
{main}()

require_once('..../bootstrap/start.php')

require('..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php

Illuminate/Config/EnvironmentVariables->load()

Illuminate/Config/FileEnvironmentVariablesLoader->load()

array_dot()

Illuminate\Support\Arr::dot()
```

** Please not that the ..... is a representation, not what I have in my file, just figured my personal file path was not going to help at all.

I have a .env.local.php file in the root of the main project directory with the correct DB info in it.

Anyone have an idea of what has happened?

Thanks in advance. And if you need any more info, please let me know, I don't know what you might need on this one.

Comment: Whatever you're passing in is not an array, obviously. But since you haven't shown any actual code, we can't help you figure out why.

Comment: Yeah I was not sure what code might be needed. But actually, I just rethought it, it is something with the environment variables. It seems that even though I had a .env.local.php file, it was still using the app/config/local/database.php file.

Comment: So I removed my .env.local.php file and changed the local/database.php file to reflect correct credentials and it seems to work. Guess I will have to look into my environment variables and see what my issue is there.    

Thanks for your time, I am still in the process of learning Laravel so sometimes it is hard to know what I need to post (even though this is my first post).

Thanks!

Comment: I got it now, I was forgetting to "return" the $_ENV array in my .env.local.php file. Sorry, but at least this might point someone in the right direction if they do the same.